# mod_rewrite for two different pages

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have two pages:

```
categories.php
```

in categories.php page I fetch all categories.

```
news.php
```

in news page I fetch news by id.

I have used mod_rewrite for categories:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ categories.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ categories.php?url=$1

site/categori1 ----> this rule works for categorie page
```

Is it posible open mod_rewrite two different page?(categories.php and news.php)

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ news.php?url=$2
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ new.php?url=$2

site/news-title1 above rule not working for news.php page.

How can I use mod_rewrite for two different pages? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be more specific with what your regular expression is matching:

'^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$' will match *almost* everything.

You need to decide what differentiates a category page from a news page and match on that, eg:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ categories.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ categories.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ news.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ news.php?url=$1
```

You can differentiate the rules in some other way, but you do have to do it.

You could, for instance, rearrange the rules in my suggestion above to make the category rule catch everything which isn't prefixed with news:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ news.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ news.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ categories.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ categories.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 2):

`www.site.com/news-title1` and `www.site.com/category1` are basically matching same URLs and hence mod_rewrite cannot conclusively decide where to redirect. I will suggest following in addition to what you already have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^news-([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ news.php?url=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/?$ categories.php?url=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Now a URI of type `www.site.com/news-some-title` will be forwarded to `www.site.com/news.php?url=some-title` (**anything starting with `news-`**)

and URI of type `www.site.com/some-category` will be forwarded to `www.site.com/category.php?url=some-category`